# AJAX Wordpress url

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have problem with AJAX.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", // our PHP handler file
    data: "myDataString",
    success:function(results){
        alert(results);
    }
)};
```

Without authorization this request does not work. How can I add custom URL to action in WP?

Comment: whats your aim ? u wanna get data after login?

Comment: No, i want ajax request without autorization.

Comment: you want to put data without authorization?

Comment: Yep, i want put data without authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very clear, however i'll help you to add an AJAX action for both logged and non logged in users.

```
// Add this to functions.php
// Let's enqueue our javascript file
function include_ajax_js() {

    wp_register_script(
        'ajax-custom-script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );

   // Add data your script that you can normally
   // only get from the server side of WordPress.

   $localize = array(
       'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
       // Securing your WordPress plugin AJAX calls using nonces
       'auth' => wp_create_nonce('_check__ajax_100')
   );
   wp_localize_script('ajax-custom-script', 'custom_ajax_vars', $localize);

   wp_enqueue_script('ajax-custom-script');

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );

// Let's make function to handle AJAX requests
function my_ajax_action() {

    // Check nonce
    check_ajax_referer( '_check__ajax_100', 'nonce_field' );

    // Let's display some useful information
    // May be you need to check if the user is still logged in

    $user_greeting = is_user_logged_in() ? 'Hello User !' : 'Hello Guest !';
    $data = array( 'msg' => $user_status );

    echo json_encode($data); // encode the output to JSON
    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_check_status', 'my_ajax_action' );
// wp_ajax_nopriv_ executes for users that are not logged in
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_check_status', 'my_ajax_action' );
```

Enough PHP for now, let's create ajax.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        // We can easily get the AJAX Url from the object we've created before
        url: custom_ajax_vars.ajaxurl,
        // Data should be sent as an object
        data: { action: check_status, nonce_field: custom_ajax_vars.nonce },
        success:function(data){
            alert(data.status);
        }
    )}
})
})
```

Comment: In wordpress we can use this construction for call any action:
`add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_action_name", "action_name");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var username = "user123";
var password = "pass123";

//var username = "";
//var password = "";    
var headers = {}; //list of headers

if(username && password) //user and pass exists
    headers['Authorization'] = "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password);

     jQuery.ajax({

     type:"POST",

    url: http://siteurl.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php,

  data: "myDataString",
    headers: headers, //use our headers 
     success:function(results){

      alert(results);

    }

    )};
```